# Why Breadcrumbs not visible?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm using the [Recruiter Distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter) want to enable breadcrumbs. I try the module  [Path breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) or [Custom breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs). Still they are not visible.
I also copied this code to the page.tpl.php of Cloudy theme.

```
<?php
 print $breadcrumb 
?>
```

The Recruiter Distribution is using the [Cloudy theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudy).

Am I  missing something?

Comment: are breadcrumbs turned on in appearance/settings?

Comment: There is no checkbox for Breadcrumbs in the Global settings of the themes.

Comment: @sokratis, I think you should report this to the cloudy theme issue queue.